# Detect if code is in a Framework vs. App vs. Bundle

Tags: ios, c++11, objective-c++, mach-o

Is there a way to detect if the code being compiled is in a Framework, a Bundle, or a Dynamic Library?

The reason is because of a crash reporter library that needs to know if a struct variable exists before taking the address of it..

IE:

```
#ifdef MH_EXECUTE_SYM
return (uint8_t*)&_mh_execute_header;
#else
return (uint8_t*)&_mh_dylib_header;
#endif
```

The problem is that `MH_EXECUTE_SYM`, `MH_BUNDLE_SYM`, `MH_DYLIB_SYM` is always defined for every kind of executable, bundle, framework..

So I need a way of determining which struct variable to take the address of.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you really just want to get a pointer to the appropriate `mach_header_64` (or `mach_header` on 32-bit systems).

If you have a pointer, you can use the `dladdr` function to find out which (if any) mach-o it was loaded from. That function fills in a `Dl_info` structure which includes, amongst other things, a pointer to the `mach_header_64` for the mach-o.

```
// For TARGET_RT_64_BIT:
#import <TargetConditionals.h>

// For dladdr:
#import <dlfcn.h>

// For mach_header and mach_header_64:
#import <mach-o/loader.h>

#ifdef TARGET_RT_64_BIT

struct mach_header_64 *mach_header_for_address(const void *address) {
    Dl_info info;
    if (dladdr(address, &info) == 0) {
        // address doesn't point into a mach-o.
        return 0;
    }
    struct mach_header_64 *header = (struct mach_header_64 *)info.dli_fbase;
    if (header->magic != MH_MAGIC_64) {
        // Something went wrong...
        return 0;
    }

    return header;
}

#else

struct mach_header mach_header_for_address(const void *address) {
    Dl_info info;
    if (dladdr(address, &info) == 0) {
        // address doesn't point into a mach-o.
        return 0;
    }
    struct mach_header *header = (struct mach_header *)info.dli_fbase;
    if (header->magic != MH_MAGIC) {
        // Something went wrong...
        return 0;
    }

    return header;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Could you please add an example where do I get `address`?

Comment: Take the address of any global function or variable. For example, `(void *)&main`.